# nw_socket_handle_socket_event when accessing GraphQL API through react native app

Tags: xcode, react-native, api, graphql

I've searched online extensively for a resolution to this issue. It's frustrating because my colleague running the same app and same code branch does not experience it.
The problem:
When calling via react-native command line, at the point our app requests the API endpoint

```
  try {
    return await graphQLClient.request<T>(document, variables, {
      memberGenKey: memberGenKey,
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log('e', ex);
  }
```

The execution falls to the `catch` and outputs  `LOG  e [TypeError: Network request failed]`. From Xcode, the specific error is

`[connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C71.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]`

I've logged the `document`, `variables`, and `memberGenKey` values. They are all correct.

I've tested the endpoint in both PostMan and an Apollo sandbox. The query executes and returns the correct result.

In Postman settings, if I enable `SSL Certificate verification` and disable `CA Certificates`, and run the query, I get the following error

[image: Postman error]

If I enable both settings and include the `cert.pem` file, the query works. However, I've been told the API endpoint does not require authentication.

**So what could possibly cause the connection to be refused from within the app?** I am out of ideas and no one I work with seems to know a solution either. I'm hoping someone here has encountered and resolved this issue because I'm dead in the water until it's fixed.

**react-native info**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.6.5
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
    Memory: 3.05 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.5.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/mstelly/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 14.0.1/14A400 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-native: 0.71.7 => 0.71.7
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

UPDATE: I just learned that this problem is actually two problems, one of which I resolved today. For whatever reason, the `network request` error was caused by the server not authenticating the request from my ios simulator. I discovered this when I tried to reach an external endpoint from Safari in the simulator. The call failed.

When I exported the enterprise ssl cert and drag/drop it onto the simulator, it installed and boom, the simulator displayed the data. My colleague running the same app on the same network did not have to do this. His version just worked. In the years I've worked with ios, I've never had to add a cert to the simulator. Seems like there's a first time for everything.

However, that only solves half the problem, although the most critical one. The other part `[connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C108.1.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]` remains unsolved. I'm working on that next.

Comment: I have the same Problem between Xcode simulator and local Vapor.
Safari & Postman works.   iOS code doesn't: nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR 61
Status Code: 200